# document.querySelectorAll() в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, queryselectorall

Здравствуйте! Я не давно в JS.. научился на события мыши эффекты накладывать.. а с массивами еле еле пока...

есть три инпута с Type="number" 
при нажатии на кнопку собирается Value, и меняются data атрибуты другого элемента... я  через айдишники всё уже запилил но хотелось бы попроще как то через:

var a = document.querySelectorAll('[type="number"]');

Как все их ( 3-х инпутов) Value в массив занести... желателно который со своими ключами, obj... хухлил очень долго и упорно...jQuery не понимать..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[type="number"]'));
```

[Spread оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('[type="number"]')]
```

Так же вы можете вызывать на NodeList методы массива с помощью prototype:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[type="number"]'));
```

Или даже напрямую их туда засовывать:

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
document.querySelectorAll('[type="number"]').forEach() // Теперь так можно
```

Comment: `NodeList.prototype.forEach` уже и без засовывания есть почти везде  - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: Спасибище огромное! Получилось первым методом) нужно подтягивать основы...